# How to Download PDF from Folder in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

```
[Route("pdfdownload")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Getpdfdownload(string parameter)
{
   HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

   string PdfFileName = parameter;

   string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SISource"].ToString() + "\\" + PdfFileName; 

   var dataBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

   var dataStream = new MemoryStream(dataBytes);

   return new GetPDFDownload(dataStream, Request, PdfFileName);

}


public class GetPDFDownload : IHttpActionResult
{
     MemoryStream bookStuff;
 string PdfFileName;

 HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage;

 HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage;



public GetPDFDownload(MemoryStream data, HttpRequestMessage request, string filename)
{
   bookStuff = data;

   httpRequestMessage = request;

   PdfFileName = filename;
}

public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> 

ExecuteAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

    httpResponseMessage = httpRequestMessage.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    httpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(bookStuff);

    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new 

    System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");

    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = PdfFileName;

    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new 

    System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");


    return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(httpResponseMessage);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To download any file you can use the following snippet. Its short and very simple. You can customize a little bit and use it.

```
    //Route: http://localhost:56928/api/values/parameter=asdasd
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(string parameter)
    {
        var path = @"D:\Work\"+parameter;
        var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
        FileContentResult result = new FileContentResult(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path), "application/octet-stream")
        {
            FileDownloadName = fileName
        };
        return result;
    }
```

Or you can do like this:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var path = @"D:\Work\Tryouts\split.txt";
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Problem with FileContentResult Could you please explain about it

Comment: FileContentResult inherits from ActionResult so it should work anyway. What problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: IActionResult  is not working for me so that i changed that into IHttpActionResult in that FileContentResult says as missing assembly reference. Kindy give any example

Comment: Then you should return HttpResponseMessage instead of IHttpActionResult `public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            var path = @"D:\Work\Tryouts\split.txt";
            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            return result;
        }`